# Are there any solutions to this command(shell code) problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some shell codes looks like:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < (ls -la $path)
```

but, get an error 
"**-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('**"
which i can't fix it.
I do know the pipeline command can also do it well.
likes

```
ls -la $path | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

but actually I wish to do something in the loops
like change the global value

```
while read line; $((count++)); done
```

and the pipeline didn't work.

Comment: It worth bookmarking the guides [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)  (especially the Pitfalls `:)` along with [**shellcheck.net**](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: That's awesome, i'm already using it! appreciate it and also for solving my problems

Comment: Shellcheck produces [3 findings for your code](https://pastebin.com/gaLq06fM). You should fix the problems before continuing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) is:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < <(ls -la $path)
```

But anyways, [doing it this way is not a good idea at all](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use a for loop instead:

```
for fname in "$path"/* "$path"/.*; do
  echo "$fname"
done
```

And if you need to get information about a file in the loop, use [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

Comment: Please don't suggest using `ls -la`, suggest an alternate safe approach

Comment: I'd refer the OP to [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and remind they didn't call it `#1` for nothing `:)`  Also, this is a nit, but may be confusing to new users, since there is a `file` command, it just looks odd as a variable name as well (though it is 100% OK)

Comment: Yep, I like that, or I generally use `fname` of something similar. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider aggressively avoiding `ls` in scripts, as its output could be unpredictable.

As an alternative, consider the following:

```
count=0
for file in "$path"/.* "$path"/*; do
  [[ -e $file ]] && ((count++))
done
```

For more details on why `ls` is so undesirable, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: `let` is legitimate, but better `((count++))` using the POSIX arithmetic operators. but see comment below other answer for choice of `file` as a variable name.

Comment: If the question is tagged as `bash`, what benefit do we derive from avoiding  `let` (and perhaps `[[`).

Comment: Portability. `let` itself is a builtin in bash, the POSIX arithmetic operators as well.

Comment: There was once a time when I was once required to write POSIX shell scripts because they needed to run on a tonne of UNIX systems where only a bourne compatible shell was available.  Nowadays, with the ubiquity of Bash, I find it liberating to lean into its features.  In environments where bash will always be available (and where folks claim that they're targetting bash), I'm not sure what's wrong with using the features it provides.

Comment: `((count++))` looks cooler than `let`, and resembles posix `$((...))`